# tengo una variable en reactjs que dentro de una funcion obtiene un valor pero luego cuando la uso no ha cambiado su valor

Tags: javascript, reactjs

estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web con reactjs y me encuentro en la situacion que tengo una variable declarada en un componente, esa variable obtiene un valor cuando ejecuto una funcion incluso imprimo ese valor en consola, pero al momento de utilizar su valor para mostrarlo en una tabla es como si nunca hubiese cambiado de valor. adjunto mi codigo y una muestra de la salida en pantalla de la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Propiedades({idservicio}){
    const [opciones, setOpciones] = useState([])
    const nombres = []
    let strNombres = "valor"

    //FUNCION PARA OBTENER TODAS LAS OPCIONES PARA UN SERVICIO DETERMINADO
    const getOpciones = async(idservicio) => {
        const apiresult = await fetch('http://localhost:5106/api/PropsServicio/listByServId/' + idservicio)

        if (apiresult.ok) {
            const opcionesApi = await apiresult.json()
            setOpciones(opcionesApi.response)
            
            opcionesApi.response.map((opcion) => {
                nombres.push(opcion.descripcion)
            })
            strNombres = nombres.toString()
            console.log(strNombres)            
        }
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getOpciones(idservicio)
    },[])

    return (
        <div>{strNombres}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strNombres` podría resetar su valor en cada render, debes definir `strNombres` en el estado con `useState` y cambiarle su valor con la funcion definida para eso, así:

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Propiedades({idservicio}){
    const [opciones, setOpciones] = useState([])
    const [strNombres, setStrNombres] = useState("valor");
    const nombres = []
    //let strNombres = "valor"

    //FUNCION PARA OBTENER TODAS LAS OPCIONES PARA UN SERVICIO DETERMINADO
    const getOpciones = async(idservicio) => {
        const apiresult = await fetch('http://localhost:5106/api/PropsServicio/listByServId/' + idservicio)

        if (apiresult.ok) {
            const opcionesApi = await apiresult.json()
            setOpciones(opcionesApi.response)
            
            opcionesApi.response.map((opcion) => {
                nombres.push(opcion.descripcion)
            })
            setStrNombres(nombres.toString());
            //console.log(nombres)            
        }
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getOpciones(idservicio)
    },[])

    return (
        <div>{strNombres}</div>
    )
}
```

Comment: no explique bien esa parte, el hecho es que en cada render de ese componente strNombres debe resetear su valor para poder tomar el nuevo, pq para cada fila de la tabla el id que usara la funcion donde se establece su valor es diferente, para ponerlo en contexto....cuando se pinta cada fila de la tabla se le pasa a la funcion el idservicio, y a partir de ese id deberia mostrar unos datos, por ejemplo si donde estoy renderizando {strNombres} pongo idservicio muestra el idservicio que deberia pero al intentar la variable llega sin valor al render. saludos

Comment: pude resolver, gracias por la ayuda, ya muestra lo que necesito que muestr, ahora sucede que es como si la funcion dentro del useEffect se disparara 2 veces y el contenido lo muestra duplicado

Comment: Si estás usando react 18 y tienes activado el StrictMode esa puede ser la razón. O también dependiendo del contexto, podrías tener algún componente padre que cause que el componente se desmonte y se desmonte (lo que sería montarlo 2 veces) y por eso la doble ejecucion

Answer (score 1):

Este problema es muy comun al inicio, esto es porque react no renderiza por si solo, por eso existen los states, solo agregalo como state y te funcionara

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Propiedades({idservicio}){
    const [opciones, setOpciones] = useState([]);
    const [strNombres, setStrNombres] = useState("valor");
    const nombres = []

    //FUNCION PARA OBTENER TODAS LAS OPCIONES PARA UN SERVICIO DETERMINADO
    const getOpciones = async(idservicio) => {
        const apiresult = await fetch('http://localhost:5106/api/PropsServicio/listByServId/' + idservicio)

        if (apiresult.ok) {
            const opcionesApi = await apiresult.json()
            setOpciones(opcionesApi.response)
            
            opcionesApi.response.map((opcion) => {
                nombres.push(opcion.descripcion)
            })
            setStrNombres(nombres.toString())          
        }
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getOpciones(idservicio)
    },[])

    return (
        <div>{strNombres}</div>
    )
}
```

De igual manera te recomiendo mirar la documentación oficial: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, pude resolver asi. saludos